# What does "go out dancing" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

> I love to go out dancing. ([OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/love_2))

When I came across this sentence, I recollected the man, [Cheo Yong](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1152&bih=749&q=%EC%B2%98%EC%9A%A9%EB%AC%B4%EC%82%AC%EC%A7%84&oq=%EC%B2%98%EC%9A%A9%EB%AC%B4%EC%82%AC%EC%A7%84&gs_l=img.12...1554.1554.0.2398.1.1.0.0.0.0.118.118.0j1.1.0....0...1ac.2.51.img..1.0.0.KGeQOY-PjSo&gws_rd=ssl), who saw four legs on his bed over 1,130 years ago, when he came back late. After that, singing “two are mine, two are who’s? Though originally mine, what should I do, after deprived,” he went out, [dancing](http://video.search.naver.com/search.naver?where=video&sm=tab_jum&ie=utf8&query=%EC%B2%98%EC%9A%A9%EB%AC%B4). (This song very famous, every Korean middle school student learns the [old lyrics](http://terms.naver.com/entry.nhn?docId=562953&cid=46642&categoryId=46642) in Korean text books.)
But I can find ‘go out dancing’ is interpreted, on Korean websites, into ‘*go outside to dance*.’ Is it an idiom? Can the sentence in OALD be interpreted ‘*go outside, dancing*,’ as the dancing of the doomed guy who saw four legs in A.D.879.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, *going out* will be interpreted as "go (out of my house) to a place where people have fun". I can go out eating (to a restaurant), go out dancing (to a club, or when you are my age, a *disco*), go out drinking (to a bar).

As a general statement, this is the only common interpretation: the sentence describes a habitual act, not a specific situation.

Context changes everything though:

> I was in the room, then I went out (,)dancing.

Means indeed I went out while, at the same time, I was dancing: *I cha-cha'd my way to the door*, *I waltzed out of the room*, *I quickstepped out* or *I tangoed into the hallway*. In that last instance, obviously I am not the only one leaving the premises, because, as J.R. notes in the comments, [it takes two to tango](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takes_two_to_tango_%28idiom%29)

> I love to go *outside* dancing.

Describes my liking of actually going outdoors to dance in the open. (No, I don't do that, really.)

> After I insult everybody in the room, I love to go out dancing.

This is ambiguous, but the mention of the room indicates I may actually leave the room while showing off my sense of rhythm to the insulted. It could also mean I like to go to a club after the insults are delivered. Unless you get to know me better, you can never be sure...

Comment: You must be the life of the party before you leave. Or go out.

Comment: _I was in the room, then I went out, dancing_. This could mean that you danced out of the room, dancing your way into another room in the house; in other words: _Upon hearing the good news, I waltzed from the kitchen into the living room_.

Comment: @J.R. — I think I said just that with _I went out while I was dancing_. Ok, I did not mention the possibility of entering another room, but I fail to see the relevance...

Comment: I just thought "means indeed I went out while I was dancing" might be a little bit ambiguous, considering the O.P. is already confused about what "going out" means. I was just trying to add a little clarification where there might be some confusion. In principle, we are in agreement.

Comment: @StoneyB — My leaving is usually the _start_ of the party. People invite me to come early to celebrate my departure. Cheers often erupt at the mere _hint_ of me making myself scarce. Magicians can make me disappear, but they are _never_ ask to make me reappear.

Comment: @J.R. — I added a bit in an attempt to remove any confusion.

Comment: Excellent! Except you *can't* "tango into the hallway" – at least, not by yourself. [It takes two to tango](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takes_two_to_tango_%28idiom%29). ;^)